# Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.>Could not find bundletool-1.9.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.9.0)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, bundletool

### I have a problem, please someone help me with this
When I create the Flutter project and want to run the project using the emulator, I encounter this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.

> Could not find bundletool-1.9.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.9.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.9.0/bundletool-1.9.0.jar
> *Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

---

Maybe someone can guide me how to fix this problem, I searched the internet a lot but I didn't find a way